# How to reference a chapter after using the \setcounter{chapter}{0}

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, counters

I'm trying to create a reference the appendix. The `appendix` package is resetting the chapter and section exectly like I do and I started to notice this bug while using it...

So I use the `\setcounter` to reset the `chapter` and `section` counters and I can't use call the `\chapter{}` or `\chapter*{}` because I create a headins manually.

And when I try to reference an appendix, the `\ref` returns the number of the last section (which is prior to the appendicis section) instead of a number of the required appendix.

What I need is the `\ref` to output the appendix a letter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\apx}[1]{
    \clearpage
    \stepcounter{chapter}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge #1}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}
\section{sec11}
The first appendix is Appendix~\ref{apxA} % 2.2 instead of A
\section{sec12}
\chapter{ch2}
The second appendix is Appendix~\ref{apxB} % 2.2 instead of B
\section{sec21}
\section{sec22}


% Appendicis

\setcounter{chapter}{0}% 
\setcounter{section}{0}%

\apx{appendix A} \label{apxA}
\blindtext
\apx{appendix B} \label{apxB}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter` (but it would be better to use `\chapter` )

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `\appendix`?

Comment: The `\appendix` internally does exactly what I do. `\refstepcounter` helped, thanks!

Comment: Resetting the `chapter` counter by the `appendix` package or `\appendix` command is not a bug -- it's done by design

Answer (score 0):

I should have used `\refstepcounter` instead of the `\stepcounter`. Why is it two different commands, strange...

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\apx}[1]{
    \clearpage
    \refstepcounter{chapter} % <--------------
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge #1}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}
\section{sec11}
The first appendix is Appendix~\ref{apxA} % A
\section{sec12}
\chapter{ch2}
The second appendix is Appendix~\ref{apxB} % B
\section{sec21}
\section{sec22}


% Appendicis

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}} % <--------------

\apx{appendix A} \label{apxA}
\blindtext
\par
\thechapter
\apx{appendix B} \label{apxB}
\blindtext
\par
\thechapter

\end{document}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you want to have working labels, than `\refstepcounter` is your friend -- that's why it's called `ref`-stepcounter, because it sets the label of the last counter being stepped (better: It sets `\@currentlabel` which is used by `\label` then to set up cross-reference information!)

Comment: Are there more **ref**-commands? Strange that they thought someone does not work with refs

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Why can I need `\stepcounter ` shich does not affect refs?

Comment: any counter that is not referencable, in the format: `page` and `footnote` for example, but why do it "by hand" which means that you need to worry about this (and still need to worry about missing `%` at ends of lines which could make spurious white space, and missing `\par` at end of `\Huge` which will mean that any titles longer than a line will be set on an incorrect baseline spacing.

Comment: Note that it is usual when somebody answers in comments to ask that person to write an answer rather than writing one yourself. However, I don't think @DavidCarlisle is in desperate need of reputation points :-).

Comment: The total approach screws up the label/reference system just due to the fact that `\chapter` is not used here.

Comment: unfortunately, the `\chapter` is not flexible enough or I just don't want to dive into rewriting half of its commands. It's really easier to do by hand